# R shiny and R session environment

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-sf

Is there a way to get an object from an R shiny app (locally running) to the R session environment without downloading? Similar to printing out info from R shiny to console but with objects. Below is a app that lets the user draw a geometry (polygon) and then download that polygon to a zip file; however, the object (sf) is already in the R shiny environment and it would be a nice user experience if they didn't have to download the zip and then unzip it to then use in current R session environment. I'm out of thoughts and ideas... Thanks.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(zip)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(leafem)
viz_A <- function() {

  grp <- c("USGS Topo", "USGS Imagery Only", "USGS Imagery Topo",
           "USGS Shaded Relief", "Hydrography")
  att <- paste0("<a href='https://www.usgs.gov/'>",
                "U.S. Geological Survey</a> | ",
                "<a href='https://www.usgs.gov/laws/policies_notices.html'>",
                "Policies</a>")
  GetURL <- function(service, host = "basemap.nationalmap.gov") {
    sprintf("https://%s/arcgis/services/%s/MapServer/WmsServer", host, service)
  }

  map <- leaflet::leaflet()
  map <- leaflet::addWMSTiles(map, GetURL("USGSTopo"),
                              group = grp[1], attribution = att, layers = "0")
  map <- leaflet::addWMSTiles(map, GetURL("USGSImageryOnly"),
                              group = grp[2], attribution = att, layers = "0")
  map <- leaflet::addWMSTiles(map, GetURL("USGSImageryTopo"),
                              group = grp[3], attribution = att, layers = "0")
  map <- leaflet::addWMSTiles(map, GetURL("USGSShadedReliefOnly"),
                              group = grp[4], attribution = att, layers = "0")

  opt <- leaflet::WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE)
  map <- leaflet::addWMSTiles(map, GetURL("USGSHydroCached"),
                              group = grp[5], options = opt, layers = "0")
  map <- leaflet::hideGroup(map, grp[5])
  opt <- leaflet::layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE)
  map <- leaflet::addLayersControl(map, baseGroups = grp[1:4],
                                   overlayGroups = grp[5], options = opt)
  map %>%
    leafem::addMouseCoordinates(epsg = "EPSG:4326", proj4string = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

}

shiny::shinyApp(
  
  ui = shiny::fluidPage(leaflet::leafletOutput('aoi'),
                        shiny::textInput('export_filename', label = 'Filename'),
                        shiny::downloadButton("downloadData", label = "Download")
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    output$aoi <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
      
      viz_A() %>% leaflet::setView(lat = 48.91167, lng = -114.90246, zoom = 4) %>%
        leafem::addMouseCoordinates(epsg = "EPSG:4326", proj4string = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") %>%
        leaflet.extras::addDrawToolbar(polylineOptions = F, circleOptions = T, markerOptions = T,
                                       circleMarkerOptions = F, polygonOptions = T)
      
      
    })
    
    
    shiny::observeEvent(input$aoi_draw_new_feature, {
      
      
      
      feat <- input$aoi_draw_new_feature
      coords <- unlist(feat$geometry$coordinates)
      coords <- matrix(coords, ncol = 2, byrow = T)
      
      
      poly <- sf::st_sf(sf::st_sfc(sf::st_polygon(list(coords))), crs = sf::st_crs(4326)) %>% sf::st_as_sf()
      
      maps <- shiny::reactive(poly)
      
     
      leaflet::leafletProxy('aoi') %>% leafem::addMouseCoordinates(epsg = "EPSG:4326", proj4string = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
      
      
      map_update <- shiny::reactive({ viz_A() %>% leafem::addMouseCoordinates(epsg = "EPSG:4326", proj4string = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") %>%
          leaflet::addPolygons(data = maps() )})
      
      
      
      output$aoi <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
        
        map_update() %>%
          leaflet.extras::addDrawToolbar(polylineOptions = F, circleOptions = T, markerOptions = T,
                                         circleMarkerOptions = T, polygonOptions = T)
      })
      output$downloadData <- shiny::downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
          
          paste0(input$export_filename, ".zip")
        },
        content = function(file) {
          tmp.path <- dirname(file)
          name.base <- file.path(tmp.path, input$export_filename)
          name.glob <- paste0(name.base, ".*")
          name.shp  <- paste0(name.base, ".shp")
          name.zip  <- paste0(name.base, ".zip")
          sf::st_write(maps(), dsn = name.shp, layer = "shpExport",
                       driver = "ESRI Shapefile", quiet = TRUE, delete_dsn = T)
          zip::zipr(zipfile = name.zip, files = Sys.glob(name.glob))
          shiny::req(file.copy(name.zip, file))
          
        })
   
    }
    )
    
  }
  
)
```

Comment: You can use `variable <<- value` syntax to assign an object from your app to a variable in the global environment. It will be available when exited from the app

Comment: Thanks. Did you want to answer?

Comment: Better upvote my answer there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811903/in-shiny-update-datatable-with-new-values-from-user-input/40812507#40812507

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Shiny, update DataTable with new values from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811903/in-shiny-update-datatable-with-new-values-from-user-input)